# How can I trigger click on a child anchor element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
$('#Container a:nth-child(2)').click();
```

This is inside a function. When the function is performed I want it to click on the second anchor element.

Comment: JQuery is not strictly required for this but it will simplify the job. Also, did you try to run the code? Is it working?

Comment: Please show your markup.

Comment: No it doesn't work

Comment: Protip: tags are text in a file. _Elements_ are in your web page.

Answer (score 0):

click function in jQuery is an event listener,
your syntax will be valid on pure javaScript

Comment: document.querySelector("#container a:nth-child(2)").click();

Comment: is it like that?

Comment: yeah, looks okay to me